# multidimensional array, transpositional values and merged result

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge, array-key

I have and array $aArg with these values

```
array ( 0 => 'reviewed_entity', 1 => 'kiosk', )
array ( 0 => 'tripadvisor', 1 => 'tripadvisor2', )
array ( 0 => 'google', 1 => 'google2', )
array ( 0 => 'yahoo', 1 => 'yahoo2', )
```

I need to make it appear as below.

```
array ('kiosk'  =>  array ( 'tripadvisor' => 'tripadvisor2','google' => 'google2','yahoo' => 'yahoo2',));
```

- Please note a few things Kiosk is the value of the [1] of first array. and it's now the parent array'
- Other arrays have values of [0] transpose as key for [1]
- All the arrays have been merged into one.

Thank you guys I have had sleepless nights trying to get final merge result, please share with me the fastest way to get desired results

Comment: What language is this? Please [edit] the question and add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input array doesn't seems to be correct. I thought it was like the following..

```
<?php $aArg = array(
array ( 0 => 'reviewed_entity', 1 => 'kiosk', ),
array ( 0 => 'tripadvisor', 1 => 'tripadvisor2', ),
array ( 0 => 'google', 1 => 'google2', ),
array ( 0 => 'yahoo', 1 => 'yahoo2', ));


$newArr = array($aArg[0][1] => array());
$i = 0;
foreach($aArg as $arr) {
  if($i) {
    $newArr[$aArg[0][1]][$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
  }
  $i ++;
} 
var_export($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it's fastest but i hope you will get the desired results. The following code is in PHP..

```
$newArr = array($aArg[0][1] => array());

$i = 0;
foreach($aArg as $arr) {
  if($i) {
    $newArr[$aArg[0][1]][$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
  }
  $i ++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not getting the right result. I get "array ( 'e' => array ( ), )array ( 'e' => array ( 'k' => 'i', ), )" see http://ideone.com/ziXyG8